# Docker Container Not Showing Up

Tags: node.js, docker, express

I am following along with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zUHg7xjIqQ&t=46s) tutorial to learn how to containerize a node.js / express application I'm working on. Everything seems to be working fine, except that when I `docker ps` after building the container, I don't see my running container.

Node.js / express code:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hi there")
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Listening On Port 3000"))
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /untitled
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
COPY . ./
CMD node server.js
```

My working directory is "untitled" because that's the default name that Webstorm gives my project and I haven't changed it yet.

The image build seems to have worked fine

[image]

As well as the container build

[image]

But `docker ps` isn't showing me any containers

[image]

Comment: Try `docker logs container` as well as `docker ls -a` to see all containers including stopped. Then tell us the results.

Comment: Ok so docker "Cannot find express." I'll edit my question shortly--I need to go right now.

Comment: Also show your `package.json` it needs to have express as a dependency for it to actually install.

Comment: Are you sure about `app.listen(const express = require("express");`? Should be something like `app.listen(port, () => { ... });`

Comment: I think I copied / pasted the code wrong. My actual code certainly doesn’t have that. I think the error is something else. Will correct shortly

Comment: Your container did run, but exit instantly. There's bug in your server code.

Comment: See updated code. I had the same experience.

Comment: I just needed to install `npm install express` before building the docker image. Previously, it wasn't in the `package.json` as you guys mentioned. Why am I only catching this now? The server code ran on my local machine without this step